# How do I access JSON elements inside passed data?

Tags: reactjs

I've got my parent component iterating through an array and passing each "row" from mongo to the child component.

```
    <tbody>
         {this.state.claims.map ( claim => <ClaimRow claim= { claim } /> )}
    </tbody>
```

The data being passed looks like this:

```
    {"_id":"5b0d5b7f035a00f06003e6b8","claimID":"123456","claimDate":"2018-05-14T00:00:00.000Z","carrier":"BCBS NJ"}
```

I'm attempting to access all of the fields inside "claim" but I can't figure out how to properly access the field.  Since there isn't a state, I am using a pure function. I just listed the fields below since I'm not able to successfully figure this out.

```
const ClaimRow = ( {claim} =this.props ) =>  (
      <div className="inline fields">
    <Form.Field>
      <tr>
        <td>  {JSON.stringify (claim)}  </td>
        <td>{claimID}</td>
        <td>{carrier}</td>
     </tr>

    </Form.Field>
  </div>
);

ClaimRow.propTypes = {
claim: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default ClaimRow;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a proper way to provide form and div tags inside . If you want to assign class name, you can assign it to the td, or give div inside . Now without these you can properly loop thru the data in the following way,

```
const ClaimRow = (props) => {
    let claim = props.claim;
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{JSON.stringify (claim)}  </td>
        <td>{claim.claimID}</td>
        <td>{claim.carrier}</td>
     </tr>
);
}

export default ClaimRow;
```

Comment: Thx Rohit but this still produces the same answer.  Cannot read property 'claimID' of undefined

Comment: Can you pls paste what the console.log shows in the current answer

Comment: Rohit Props = [object Object]

Comment: Interestingly, I'm getting the log twice  Rohit Props = {"claim":{"_id":"5b0d5b7f035a00f06003e6b8","claimID":"123456","claimDate":"2018-05-14T00:00:00.000Z","carrier":"BCBS NJ"}}
12:42:16.118 ClaimRow.js:16 Rohit Props = {"_id":"5b0d5b7f035a00f06003e6b8","claimID":"123456","claimDate":"2018-05-14T00:00:00.000Z","carrier":"BCBS NJ"}

Comment: Wow, that was it, I was calling it twice :~

Comment: Wat is the actual log??  Rohit Props = {"claim":{"_id":"5b0d5b7f035a00f06003e6b8","claimID":"123456","claimDate":"2018-05-14T00:00:00.000Z","carrier":"BCBS NJ"}}  ?? Is this the one? If so I have modified the answer with that. Pls check with the latest code

Comment: it worked, thank you.  the console.log allowed me to see that I was calling it twice from the parent page which was creating my problem. Thank you!!

Comment: k, then pls accept and upvote the answer for stack overflow community

Answer (score 0):

You should access through this.props.claim,

```
  const ClaimRow = ({claim}) =>  (     
      <tr>
        <td>{JSON.stringify(claim)}</td>
        <td>{claim.claimID}</td>
        <td>{claim.carrier}</td>
     </tr>

export default ClaimRow;
```

you can even say const { claim } = this.props, so you dont need to type this.props every time

Comment: Bruno, thanks for that but that's what I have.  {claim} = this.props and when I access claim.claimID or this.props.claim.claimID,  I get  "Cannot read property 'claimID' of undefined"

Comment: can you make sure the data you are passing is not undefined ?

Comment: the {JSON.stringify (claim) prints the data to the page like so  {"_id":"5b0d5b7f035a00f06003e6b8","claimID":"123456","claimDate":"2018-05-14T00:00:00.000Z","carrier":"BCBS NJ"}

Comment: Which edit?  I edited my code on top to show what I have for the const  const {claim} =  this.props

Comment: I just changed my answer.

Comment: My linter says that the proptypes object is forbidden and it doesn't change the behavior at all.

Answer (score 0):

Thx Rohit, the props log helped solve the problem.  Invoking the component twice was causing odd behavior and highlighting it resolved it quickly.